# Need a backuper tool

Tags: untagged

I'm a network admin, and I have to setup a backup process for 7 dirs, the dirs are on a windows remote folder about 2GB each with subdirs and files. I need backup a dir each day from 6pm.

Is there a freeware up that get this done for me?
What can you recommend?

Note:

Backup to a centralized windows 2003 server, all other matchines are windows 2003 servers, and are in the same LAN.

Comment: Are the machines you want to backup also Windows?

Comment: There are a number of questions that would be useful to provide the answer to: How remote is remote?  on the LAN, or across the internet? What is the destination of the backup: do you want to backup to hard disk on a server or to tape, is the destination Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: Do you need incremental backups? If not then rsync should work for you.

Comment: How can I make this public wiki, I don't think there's a right answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently started testing ntbackup, comes with WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Areca? Not sure if it works on the network, but for workstations it's a breeze!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use http://backup.comodo.com/ for home and the office.

I have used http://mozy.com as well in the past and had no issues.

Mozy is a pay service, Comodo has a tool that allows you to back up on a schedule very easily to anywhere.

If you are on a windows network you could use DFS to sync between a couple of disks as a Pseudo backup.

Comment: Hey, what is a DFS?

Comment: DFS is Distributed File System...it is a role you can install on Windows Server 2k3 and 2k8.  It took me a while to trust that you could put name spaces and replication would work but I will not host a file server with out it now.  <http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/storage/dfs/default.mspx>

Answer (score 0):

[JungleDisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) with an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) account is pretty reliable and while not free, is relatively inexpensive.  Looks like it'd be around $5 US for what you have.

Comment: Love JungleDisk, but I use Rackspace Cloud Files for the storage provider.

Answer (score 0):

For backing up Windows PCs over the network, I use [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) running on a Linux server. Works great with [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/cwrsync/) running on the Windows PC for access.